# Attempt to printf "+INF" but only getting "inf"

Tags: c, variables, format, printf

I would like to return `+INF` but instead, I am only returning "inf":

```
int main(void)
{
    double dubb = HUGE_VAL;
    printf("%f \n", dubb);
}
```

Am I overlooking something here? Or it is just compiler semantics?

Comment: I do not have the standard at hand, but `%+f` might give you '+inf' which is at least part of what you want.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Format_placeholders) is your friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `printf("%+F\n", dubb);` instead

'+' makes printf display the sign
'F' makes inf/nan uppercase

Comment: lol. I did this. But I was not sure if its there is a technical difference in the value "inf" and "+INF"

Answer (score 1):

You didn't tell us what C library you have. My man page on linux tells me:

> The
>                 C99 standard specifies "[-]inf" or "[-]infinity" for infinity, and a string starting with "nan" for NaN, in the case of f
>   conver‐
>                 sion, and "[-]INF" or "[-]INFINITY" or "NAN*" in the case of F conversion.

So what you observe seems to be in sync with the C99 standard. Use "%F" to have it all caps, for the `+` just put it in front.

Comment: So no technical difference in terms of the value that is returning? I know it seems like you already answered this question. This is a problem I am working on for school and the professor says in verbatim "Declare a double variable with a value set to positive infinity.  Display the value using printf with a %f format." and shows the "correct" output as "+INF"

Comment: Also not sure how to look up what c libray I am using. Here is my gcc info. i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2:

Comment: @user1787331: It is not clear what you mean by the value that it is returning. The code you show does not return a value. It sends some characters to standard output. As you report, those characters are i, n, and f. When you use “%+F”, the characters will be +, I, N, and F (or, depending on the C implementation, they could also have I, N, I, T, and Y). There is no numeric value being returned. These characters are typically intended to be viewed by humans and have the meaning humans attach to them. If you scan either “inf” or “+INF” with `scanf` using “%f”, you will get infinity in each case.